# Calling a java stored procedure in oracle using PL/SQL with boolean input parameter

Tags: plsql, boolean, java-stored-procedures, input-parameters

I am trying to write a PL/SQL block for calling a Java Stored procedure where the java method has a boolean as a paramter.

How can I translate the boolean when defining the package for the java procedure and invoking the java procedure from a PL/SQL block?

Somewhere I read that java boolean should be defined as a NUMBER in Oracle, so I tried that also but that did not work either.

Does anyone have an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not work, you will have to declare your java parameter as number instead of boolean and pass 1/0 for true /false. Alternatively use a char and some encoding that works for you.

Comment: not suppported by JDBC driver see  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/apxtblsh.htm#i1005380